# Change Deja-Dup storage location from local folder to external drive

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I started taking backup to a local folder using Deja-Dup some months ago. Now, the size of the folder has grown quite large and I want to move it to an external drive.

Can I just copy the `~/deja-dup` folder to the external drive?

And then change the storage location in the Backups GUI as follows:
[image]

After this, is it now possible to delete the local `~/deja-dup` folder and start a new backup from the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The next time you run a backup, you may get a error message stating that the storage device has changed. Just reselect it  and proceed.

It would be prudent to try restores and backups before deleting the original.

Comment: Thanks. I did the following: 1) copied `~/deja-dup` to the external drive. 2) moved the local folder to a new name: `mv ~/deja-dup ~/deja-dup2`, 3) changed storage location in the GUI (as shown above in my question), 4) changed folder name in the GUI to `deja-dup`, 5) chose "Back Up Now" in the GUI, 5) after backup completed, and I checked it looked ok: `rm -rf ~/deja-dup2`